# create a drag and drop category builder for cms

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I am trying to build a drag and drop category builder. I like the way the wordpress custom menu works but my problem is that the website i am creating it for has up to 6 sub categories and about 60-70 categories. I would rather build the menu then click a save menu button to place onto a mysql database so its not always draining resources with every change. I have hunted the web for 2 days now to try and find the right answer. Would anyone care to point me in the right direction?
I have looked at the nestedSortable jQuery Plugin but i have to be able to edit the category names or delete the categories completely.
 Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please be more specific about the exact problem that you're having?  Your question is rather nebulous, and seems to span the entire application architecture (ie. I'm totally unclear as to whether you're asking about the client-side, the server-side, or both?).  I suspect that's why you haven't had any responses yet, so anything you can do to clarify your question will likely help you get a response.

Comment: I need to write in the admin section a menu tree for the categories that i have. currently there are about 20 main categories and these have sub-categories and these have subcategories. This can be up to 6 sub categories deep. THe system at the moment allow me to build the category tree but if i want to move a sub category to a different sub category etc.I would like to do this using a drag and drop function.I am willing to setup a seperate table in my DB to handle the tree.The nested Sortable example mentioned above looks good but it does not seem to tell you about saving or getting the data.

Comment: I would also need the option to remove a category/sub category or edit the name of the category etc.. Once the menu is then how i like it i can press a save button and will save to the database. I think if it saved on every move it would overload the database. If i editted a category name it would need to update the Data database for all items with that category.

Answer (score 0):

[ImpressPages CMS](http://www.impresspages.org) gives you menu management in drag & drop fashion.

Comment: Yes it looks good but the whole cms is already done. Its just the category menu left to do..